# How to enable offline PWA app with Electron?

Tags: electron, progressive-web-apps

I created a progressive web app and am using electron for app distribution to use some native features.

The PWA app works fine offline in Google Chrome.

The PWA updates work fine in the electron app but starting app **offline** fails to load anything. Using the inspector, the service workers are running.

[image: service workers view in electron]

No errors in the console and page is blank.

Is there a trick I am missing ?

PS: when loading page online, the network tab shows that all assets except the index page are served by the service worker. Oh, and on Google chrome, there is a (disk cache) for index page. This might be it.

Answer (score 2):

After more testing I realised that this was an issue with my webpack configuration.

I use WorkboxPlugin to build the manifest and it was placed **before** HtmlWebpackPlugin and needs to come last. This was why the index page was not working: it was not in the manifest.